# print_r for multiple selected values after json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I am experimenting with showing selected data from an API response in a form submission confirmation in wordpress. This will be with POST in reality but have used GET for testing. I have the following which works for showing a single value from the JSON response ('id' in this case). I want to know how to write the print_r instruction to print 2 or 3 of the values (by name rather than position). For example show the 'id' and the 'login' values. I've used github api for demo.

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_4', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.github.com/users/someuser' );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
echo 'An error happened';
} else {
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
$data = json_decode( $body );
}

$confirmation .= print_r( $data->id, true );
return $confirmation;

}
```

I was assuming something like

```
$confirmation .= print nl2br(print_r($data->id, true), ($data->login, true));
```

but finding how to print_r multiple specific values with this '->' format is something I don't see in the manuals or forums.

Comment: The `->` is irrelevant. Your issue is trying to print multiple variables using a single print_r statement. This would be an issue for plain variables as well as object properties. You either just use multiple print_r statements concatenated together (e.g. `$confirmation .= print_r( $data->id, true )." ".print_r($data->login, true);`, or you could perhaps switch to using var_dump (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441757/printing-more-than-one-array-using-print-r-or-any-other-function-in-php) for example).

Comment: That concatenation approach solves it and adding <br/> between the " " generates the new line in this example. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->` is irrelevant. Your issue is trying to print multiple variables using a single print_r statement. This would be an issue for plain variables as well as object properties.

You either just use multiple print_r statements concatenated together (e.g. `$confirmation .= print_r( $data->id, true )." ".print_r($data->login, true);`, or you could perhaps switch to using var_dump (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441757/printing-more-than-one-array-using-print-r-or-any-other-function-in-php) for example).